# Escaping a password using mysqldump console

Tags: mysql, password

I am running a mysqldump via a bash script and have encountered a problem with a password that contains special characters.

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uUSERNAME -pPA$$W0RD DATABASE | 
                                gzip > /home/USERNAME/backups-mysql/BACKUP.gz
```

How do I escape the password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even better, don't put the username or password on the command line where it can be seen by anyone who can do `ps -ef`.

Create a control file named something like `/etc/mysqldump.cnf`:

```
[client]
user=root
password=YOUR_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

...where `client` is literal (not the name of your server) and `YOUR_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` is... well... your mysql root password.

Then invoke like this:

```
mysqldump --defaults-file=/etc/mysqldump.cnf DATABASE |                                 gzip > /home/USERNAME/backups-mysql/BACKUP.gz
```

Personally my invocation is more like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
NOW=`perl -e 'print time;'`
cd /opt/backup/mysql
mkdir $NOW
for i in `echo "show databases" | mysql -u root --password="MySqlRootPassword" | grep -v Database`; do
        mysqldump --defaults-file=/etc/mysqldump.cnf --databases $i --opt > $NOW/$i.dump
one
tar cfpz $NOW.tgz $NOW
du -sh $NOW $NOW/* > $NOW.report
rm -rf $NOW
```

I've never figured out how to use a similar `--defaults-file` parameter for mysql, however since this command runs fairly quickly the risk of exposure is much lower... although really that should be fixed.

Comment: For something similar to using `--defualts-file` for `mysql`, see http://serverfault.com/a/313965/53106

Answer (score 2):

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uUSERNAME -p'PA$$W0RD' DATABASE | 
                                gzip > /home/USERNAME/backups-mysql/BACKUP.gz
```

It works?

Comment: Yes, this worked.