# Is there a password agent for the mysql command-line client?

Tags: mysql, security, password-management

I use the mysql command line client frequently.  Sometimes I wind up typing in my password dozens of times per day, and I'm getting really tired of it.

SSH has a neat utility called ssh-agent which lets you type in your password just once at the beginning of the day.  Is there a similar utility for MySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. However, you can store your password in a [my.cnf](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html) file in your home directory. For example, on linux

```
$ cat ~/.my.cnf
[client]
password="password"
```

You can also store *user* and *host* there. These options will be used by all mysql clients unless you override them. If you often connect to the same server with the same credentials, setting these can save you a lot of typing.

You need to make sure that your my.cnf is only readable by your user. For example, `chmod 600 ~/.my.cnf`.

Answer (score 5):

Create a `~/.my.cnf` file in your $HOME with below content:

```
[mysql]
user     = root
password = pa$$w0rd
host     = mysql.server.ip.address
```

and make it can be readable by only you:

```
chmod 600 ~/.my.cnf
```

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted, but unfortunately I can't accept both answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Run the following, and type your password.

```
mysql_config_editor set --host=putYourHostHere --user=putYourUsernameHere --password
```